# Find a point in a polygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, node-js

How can I find all points in a polygon pass in queries:

My column coord is a geometry point example,

pseudo-code.

select a.* from "table" as a where ST_WITHIN(a.coord, [lng1 lat1, lng2 lat2, lng3 lat3, lng4 lat4,...])

I'm using EPSG 3857

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   points123 
WHERE  ST_Within(geom, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((lng1 lat1, lng2 lat2, lng3 lat3,...,lng1 lat1))',3857)))
```

Comment: that's exactly what I want, really thank you!